# Return unsure derived class in Generic method

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

Here is my problem. I have one base class and 2 or more derived class, I want to write a generic method to return one derived class but I don't know what type it is until it checked the passed paramater. However, I can't pass `List<Food>` to `List<T>` in `GetData<T>` as it said

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Generic.Food>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' Generic
```

**Solution 1: Error**

```
namespace Generic
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "some json document string here";
            var p = GetData<Cargo>(0, s);
        }

        static List<T> GetData<T>(int type, string src) where T : Cargo
        {
            if (type == 0)
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Food>>(src);
            else
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Paper>>(src);
        }
    }

    public abstract class Cargo
    {
        public double Price { get; set; }
    }

    public class Food : Cargo
    {
        public double Calorie { get; set; }
    }

    public class Paper : Cargo
    {
        public int Height { get; set; }
        public int Width { get; set; }
    }    
}
```

I know I could call something like this:
**Solutioon 2**

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "some json document string here";
            int type = 0;
            if (type == 0)
                GetData<Food>(s);
            else
                GetData<Paper>(s);

        }

        static List<T> GetData<T>(string src) where T : Cargo
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(src);
        }
```

and don't check the parameter inside the function.

However, is there any possible to use the first solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you `return new List<T>();`, or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry I missed one step. Because in the method I need to get some data form mongodb and deserilize BsonDocument to specified type. If I don't use the type, I can't parse to the correct object.

Comment: Again, why can't you deserialize to `T`? Can you edit your question to include a fuller example?

Comment: I edited a little bit codes. The question is I don't what exact type to parse and return before I check the passed parameter, what I should do If I want to check the parameter inside the method instead out of the method like solution 2. Sorry if  I can' explain it clearly.

Comment: Fundamentally, the issue is that `List<T>` isn't variant on the type parameter. That is, you must always provide _exactly_ the type parameter on assignment; the marked duplicate explains this in more detail. Since you apparently have to check the `type` value anyway, it doesn't seem like a hardship to check it before calling the generic method, rather than inside it.